# Extracting vectors from features - pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have the dataframe bellow:

```
+---+------+-------+                                                            
|id |string|string2|
+---+------+-------+
|1  |foo   |hello  |
|2  |bar   |hellow |
|3  |bar   |hellow |
|4  |baz   |hello  |
+---+------+-------+
```

Column `string` contains 3 values `[foo,bar,baz]` and `string2` contains 2 `[hello,hellow]`.

How can I extract vectors for each column in the following way:

If column `string` contains `foo` I want to map it to vector `[1,0,0]` , for `bar` to `[0,1,0]` and so on. Same for `string2` column (`hello->[1,0]`,`hellow->[0,1]`).

Final dataframe should look something like this:

```
+---+----------+-----------+                                                    
|id |string_vec|string2_vec|
+---+----------+-----------+
|1  |[1,0,0]   |[1,0]      |
|2  |[0,1,0]   |[0,1]      |
|3  |[0,1,0]   |[0,1]      |
|4  |[0,0,1]   |[0,1]      |
+---+----------+-----------+
```

Finally I want to combine the `_vec` columns to:

```
+---+-----------+                                                    
|id |features   |
+---+-----------+
|1  |[1,0,0,1,0]|
|2  |[0,1,0,0,1]|
|3  |[0,1,0,0,1]|
|4  |[0,0,1,0,1]|
+---+-----------+
```

I can do this with a `for` loop, but it is not efficient. My main problem is the mapping process. I guess for the rest I can use the VectorAssembler

Comment: Are you looking for [OneHotEncoder](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder.html)?

Comment: @werner OneHotEncoder outputs sparse vector, I want dense vectors.

Answer (score 2):

You can create simple `udf`

Your dataframe:

```
values = [("foo", "hello"), ("bar", "hellow"),("bar","hellow"), ("baz","hello")]

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = spark.createDataFrame(values, ["string", "string2"])
df.show()

+------+-------+
|string|string2|
+------+-------+
|   foo|  hello|
|   bar| hellow|
|   bar| hellow|
|   baz|  hello|
+------+-------+
```

**udf:**

```
def encode(string1,string2):
  values = ["foo","bar","baz","hello","hellow"]
  string_values = [string1,string2]
  return [1 if x in string_values else 0 for x in values]
  
encode_udf = udf(encode, ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

**result:**

```
df.withColumn("features", encode_udf("string","string2")).show()

+------+-------+---------------+
|string|string2|       features|
+------+-------+---------------+
|   foo|  hello|[1, 0, 0, 1, 0]|
|   bar| hellow|[0, 1, 0, 0, 1]|
|   bar| hellow|[0, 1, 0, 0, 1]|
|   baz|  hello|[0, 0, 1, 1, 0]|
+------+-------+---------------+
```

Comment: hey thanks... is there a way to not explicitly declare the values list?

Comment: @VectorXY you mean pass list as paramter? udf cant take list as paramter but you can hack throught and pass it as string then convert it to list inside the function

Comment: I mean `["foo","bar","baz","hello","hellow"]` are just examples. What happens if my values list containins thousands of records?

Comment: @VectorXY the values list are stored where and as what? at worst you can read it from the source and apply same steps

Comment: They are stored in a csv. I believe there is no point in using pyspark if I was to load the whole column to a list. I'm not an expert in any way...

Comment: @VectorXY if you want to parrelize the computation across multiple nodes pyspark make sense otherwise just use Pandas